# text wont get a background over image

Tags: html, css, fonts, background

Hey there i am having an issue where i cannot get the text to have its own background to make it readable over the image.
i am unclear as to what to do.
Please understand this is the first site i have ever made and are 3 days in, so dont be too nasty hehe.

This is the HTML

```
<aside class="top-sidebar">
    <article>
    <h2></h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text.</p>
    </article>
</aside>
```

this is the CSS

```
.top-sidebar {
    border-radius: 2px;
   -moz-border-radius: 2px;
     -o-border-radius: 2px;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 1% 5%;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-left: 0.5%;
    width: 29.5%;
    height: 160px;
    float: left;
    background: #fff url(Images/socialnight.jpg) no-repeat ;
    background-size: 100% 100% ;
    background-position: 0% 0%;


}


.top-sidebar article {
position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    right: 0px;
        left: 45%;
        width: 60%;
        font-size: 90%
}


p span { 
   color: white; 
   font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
   letter-spacing: -1px;  
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   padding: 10px; 
}
```

Comment: Please don't include information that is not relevant to the question. Your "SIDE NOTE" should be removed. We also don't need to know the name of your website (that could be considered as spam by many)

Comment: Post it in format of Question & Answer if you are going to self-answer!

Comment: which bit of text do you want to add background to?

Comment: @RaviDhoriyaツ: OP is not self answering, I think you just missed what the question was

Comment: @musefan Okay, sorry! :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your CSS is targeting `p span` (which means `span` element contained within a `p` tag). You don't have any `span` elements in your HTML, so either add a `span` or remove that from your CSS so you just target `p`.

Something like this:

```
p { 
   color: white; 
   font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
   letter-spacing: -1px;  
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   padding: 10px; 
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/0j5d8kf3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px;
```

Try the text shadow property it will make your text more visible

Comment: This isn't the place for suggestions on improvement (unless you are going to provide an answer to go with it). The OP has a clear problem stated and answers should aim to solve that. Answer the question, and then expand with your suggestion on alternate methods if you wish